# Extracting Elements using XQuery/SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm having zero success parsing the PartnerDescription elements from the /ShippingDocumentationNotification/ShippingBusinessDocument/ShipmentInformation/DeclarationInformation node in the XML extract below. My latest attempt:

```
SELECT  x.item.value('PartnerName[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS PartnerName
FROM    @Data.nodes('/ShippingDocumentationNotification/ShippingBusinessDocument/ShipmentInformation/DeclarationInformation/PartnerDescription/FullPartner/PartnerIdentification/PartnerName')
        AS x ( item )
```

Where @Data is an XML variable that stores an instance of the XML extract. Ultimately I'd like to parse (i.e., flatten) data contained in the PartnerIdentification and PhysicalAddress subnodes of each PartnerDescription node.  I've looked all over google and SO - if someone could just get me started, I'd be much obliged.

```
<tns:ShippingDocumentationNotification 
    xmlns:sha="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:xsd:schema:01.17" xmlns:dfpt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:FreightPaymentTerms:xsd:codelist:01.03" xmlns:uc="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Country:xsd:codelist:01.02" xmlns:drl="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:RouteLocation:xsd:codelist:01.03" xmlns:tns="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShippingDocumentationNotification:xsd:schema:02.07" xmlns:dcst="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:CustomsType:xsd:codelist:01.03" xmlns:dtrt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:TrackingReferenceType:xsd:codelist:01.06" xmlns:ssdh="urn:rosettanet:specification:system:StandardDocumentHeader:xsd:schema:01.23" xmlns:uci="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ContactInformation:xsd:schema:01.04" xmlns:updi="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ProductIdentification:xsd:schema:01.04" xmlns:upi="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:PartnerIdentification:xsd:schema:01.16" xmlns:ucs="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:CountrySubdivision:xsd:codelist:01.02" xmlns:uuom="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:UnitOfMeasure:xsd:codelist:01.04" xmlns:ulc="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Locations:xsd:schema:01.04" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:upri="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ProcessRoleIdentifier:xsd:codelist:01.11" xmlns:dsd="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:ShippingDocument:xsd:codelist:01.02" xmlns:udct="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:DocumentType:xsd:codelist:01.13" xmlns:upd="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:PhysicalDimension:xsd:schema:01.07" xmlns:pfx24="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/ae2xsd/2002/05/ae/ADB/OTMflex" xmlns:udc="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Document:xsd:schema:01.12" xmlns:rat="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:AmountType:xsd:codelist:01.03" xmlns:dat="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:ActionType:xsd:codelist:01.04" xmlns="http://xyz/" xmlns:dl="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:xsd:schema:02.22" xmlns:dic="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:Incoterms:xsd:codelist:01.03" xmlns:dsm="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:ShipmentMode:xsd:codelist:01.05" xmlns:ume="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:MonetaryExpression:xsd:schema:01.06" xmlns:dpts="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:PaymentTerms:xsd:codelist:01.04" xmlns:rssl="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:ShippingServiceLevel:xsd:codelist:01.01" xmlns:ucr="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Currency:xsd:codelist:01.03" xmlns:dp="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:xsd:schema:02.28" xmlns:dsh="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:SpecialHandling:xsd:codelist:01.04">
      <ssdh:DocumentHeader>
        <ssdh:DocumentInformation>
          <ssdh:Creation>2012-05-08T05:12:57-07:00</ssdh:Creation>
          <ssdh:DocumentIdentification>
            <ssdh:Identifier>25163</ssdh:Identifier>
            <ssdh:Type>TRUCK CLOSE</ssdh:Type>
            <ssdh:StandardDocumentIdentification>
              <ssdh:Standard>RosettaNet</ssdh:Standard>
              <ssdh:Version>11.11</ssdh:Version>
            </ssdh:StandardDocumentIdentification>
          </ssdh:DocumentIdentification>
        </ssdh:DocumentInformation>
        <ssdh:Receiver>
          <upi:PartnerIdentification>
            <upi:PartnerName />
            <DUNS xmlns="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:DataType:xsd:schema:01.04">894694306</DUNS>
          </upi:PartnerIdentification>
        </ssdh:Receiver>
        <ssdh:Sender>
          <upi:PartnerIdentification>
            <upi:PartnerName>CISCO</upi:PartnerName>
            <DUNS xmlns="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:DataType:xsd:schema:01.04">678543210</DUNS>
          </upi:PartnerIdentification>
        </ssdh:Sender>
      </ssdh:DocumentHeader>
      <tns:ShippingBusinessDocument>
        <dat:ActionType>ADD</dat:ActionType>
        <tns:HeaderInformation>
          <tns:PackingList>
            <udc:DateTime>2012-03-01T00:39:54-07:00</udc:DateTime>
            <udct:DocumentType>SHD</udct:DocumentType>
            <udc:Identifier>0</udc:Identifier>
            <udc:Line>0</udc:Line>
            <udc:Revision>F</udc:Revision>
          </tns:PackingList>
          <tns:ShippingDocument>
            <udc:DateTime>2012-03-01T00:39:54-07:00</udc:DateTime>
            <udct:DocumentType>SAO</udct:DocumentType>
            <udc:Identifier>51548069</udc:Identifier>
            <udc:Line>1</udc:Line>
            <udc:Revision>Standard - JPN</udc:Revision>
          </tns:ShippingDocument>
          <tns:ShippingOrderInformation>
            <dl:OrderInformation>
              <ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                <ulc:Authority>Cisco Systems</ulc:Authority>
                <ulc:Identifier />
              </ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
              <dl:OrderAllocationDate>2012-03-16T00:00:00-07:00</dl:OrderAllocationDate>
              <dl:OrderReference>
                <udc:DateTime>2012-05-08T05:12:57-07:00</udc:DateTime>
                <udct:DocumentType>PUO</udct:DocumentType>
                <udc:Identifier>X9055411-K2501</udc:Identifier>
              </dl:OrderReference>
              <dl:TotalAmount>
                <ume:Amount>6422.09</ume:Amount>
                <ucr:Currency>USD</ucr:Currency>
              </dl:TotalAmount>
            </dl:OrderInformation>
            <tns:RequestingOrderInformation>
              <udc:BusinessDocumentReference>
                <udct:DocumentType>SAO</udct:DocumentType>
                <udc:Identifier>51548069-1</udc:Identifier>
              </udc:BusinessDocumentReference>
              <tns:IsOrderToBeMerged>0</tns:IsOrderToBeMerged>
              <tns:OrderReference>
                <udc:DateTime>2012-05-08T05:12:57-07:00</udc:DateTime>
                <udct:DocumentType>SNC</udct:DocumentType>
                <udc:Identifier>0</udc:Identifier>
                <udc:Line>1</udc:Line>
                <udc:Revision>1</udc:Revision>
                <udc:SubLine>1</udc:SubLine>
              </tns:OrderReference>
            </tns:RequestingOrderInformation>
            <tns:RequestingOrderInformation>
              <udc:BusinessDocumentReference>
                <udct:DocumentType>SAO</udct:DocumentType>
                <udc:Identifier>51548069-1</udc:Identifier>
              </udc:BusinessDocumentReference>
              <tns:IsOrderToBeMerged>0</tns:IsOrderToBeMerged>
              <tns:OrderReference>
                <udc:DateTime>2012-05-08T05:12:57-07:00</udc:DateTime>
                <udct:DocumentType>SNC</udct:DocumentType>
                <udc:Identifier>0</udc:Identifier>
                <udc:Line>1</udc:Line>
                <udc:Revision>1</udc:Revision>
                <udc:SubLine>2</udc:SubLine>
              </tns:OrderReference>
            </tns:RequestingOrderInformation>
          </tns:ShippingOrderInformation>
        </tns:HeaderInformation>
        <tns:ShipmentInformation>
          <tns:ContainerTotalCount>1</tns:ContainerTotalCount>
          <dl:CustomsInformation>
            <dl:Customs>
              <uc:Country>US</uc:Country>
              <dcst:CustomsType>EXP</dcst:CustomsType>
              <dl:EntryNumber>77-0059951</dl:EntryNumber>
              <dl:Identifier />
            </dl:Customs>
          </dl:CustomsInformation>
          <tns:DeclarationInformation>
            <tns:Declarant>
              <upi:SpecifiedFullPartner schemaVersion="this choice is requried" />
            </tns:Declarant>
            <tns:IsInformationComplete>1</tns:IsInformationComplete>
            <upi:PartnerDescription>
              <upi:FullPartner>
                <uci:ContactInformation>
                  <uci:Contact />
                  <uci:Phone />
                </uci:ContactInformation>
                <ulc:Location>
                  <ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                    <ulc:Authority>Cisco Systems</ulc:Authority>
                    <ulc:Identifier>CCI+CI+PL+PL2+SLI</ulc:Identifier>
                  </ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                </ulc:Location>
                <upi:PartnerIdentification>
                  <upi:PartnerName>CISCO SYSTEMS G.K.</upi:PartnerName>
                  <ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                    <ulc:Authority>Cisco Systems</ulc:Authority>
                    <ulc:Identifier>68268</ulc:Identifier>
                  </ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                </upi:PartnerIdentification>
                <ulc:PhysicalAddress>
                  <ulc:AddressLine1>Midtown Tower</ulc:AddressLine1>
                  <ulc:AddressLine2>9-7-1, Akasaka</ulc:AddressLine2>
                  <ulc:AddressLine3>Minato-ku</ulc:AddressLine3>
                  <ulc:AddressLine4 />
                  <ulc:AddressLine5 />
                  <ulc:CityName>Tokyo, 107-6227</ulc:CityName>
                  <uc:Country>JP</uc:Country>
                  <ucs:CountrySubdivision />
                  <ulc:PostalCode />
                  <ulc:PostOfficeBox />
                </ulc:PhysicalAddress>
                <upri:ProcessRoleIdentifier>IMB</upri:ProcessRoleIdentifier>
              </upi:FullPartner>
            </upi:PartnerDescription>
            <upi:PartnerDescription>
              <upi:FullPartner>
                <uci:ContactInformation>
                  <uci:Contact>None</uci:Contact>
                  <uci:Phone />
                </uci:ContactInformation>
                <ulc:Location>
                  <ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                    <ulc:Authority>Cisco Systems</ulc:Authority>
                    <ulc:Identifier>CCI+CI+PL+PL2+SLI</ulc:Identifier>
                  </ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                </ulc:Location>
                <upi:PartnerIdentification>
                  <upi:PartnerName>CISCO SYSTEMS G.K.</upi:PartnerName>
                  <ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                    <ulc:Authority>Cisco Systems</ulc:Authority>
                    <ulc:Identifier />
                  </ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
                </upi:PartnerIdentification>
                <ulc:PhysicalAddress>
                  <ulc:AddressLine1>C/o Schenker Logistics</ulc:AddressLine1>
                  <ulc:AddressLine2>MIDTOWN TOWER</ulc:AddressLine2>
                  <ulc:AddressLine3>9-7-1, AKASAKA</ulc:AddressLine3>
                  <ulc:AddressLine4 />
                  <ulc:AddressLine5 />
                  <ulc:CityName>MINATO-KU</ulc:CityName>
                  <uc:Country>JP</uc:Country>
                  <ucs:CountrySubdivision>TOKYO</ucs:CountrySubdivision>
                  <ulc:PostalCode>107-6227</ulc:PostalCode>
                  <ulc:PostOfficeBox />
                </ulc:PhysicalAddress>
                <upri:ProcessRoleIdentifier>ITT</upri:ProcessRoleIdentifier>
              </upi:FullPartner>
            </upi:PartnerDescription>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
'urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShippingDocumentationNotification:xsd:schema:02.07' AS tns,
'urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:PartnerIdentification:xsd:schema:01.16' AS upi,
'urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Locations:xsd:schema:01.04' AS ulc )
SELECT 
    pid.c.value('(upi:PartnerName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS PartnerName,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:AddressLine1/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine1,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:AddressLine2/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine2,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:AddressLine3/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine3,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:AddressLine4/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine4,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:AddressLine5/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine5,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:CityName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS CityName,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:Country/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Country,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:CountrySubdivision/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS CountrySubdivision,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:PostalCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS PostalCode,
    pa.c.value('(ulc:PostOfficeBox/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS PostOfficeBox

FROM @Data.nodes('/tns:ShippingDocumentationNotification/tns:ShippingBusinessDocument/tns:ShipmentInformation/tns:DeclarationInformation/upi:PartnerDescription/upi:FullPartner') fp(c)
    CROSS APPLY fp.c.nodes('upi:PartnerIdentification') AS pid(c) 
    CROSS APPLY fp.c.nodes('ulc:PhysicalAddress') AS pa(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two examples:

```
-- Use namespace wildcard
SELECT  x.item.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS PartnerName 
FROM    @Data.nodes('//*:PartnerName') AS x ( item ) 

-- Specify all namespaces (longhond)
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
'urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShippingDocumentationNotification:xsd:schema:02.07' AS tns,
'urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:PartnerIdentification:xsd:schema:01.16' AS upi )           
SELECT  x.item.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS PartnerName 
FROM    @Data.nodes('/tns:ShippingDocumentationNotification/tns:ShippingBusinessDocument/tns:ShipmentInformation/tns:DeclarationInformation/upi:PartnerDescription/upi:FullPartner/upi:PartnerIdentification/upi:PartnerName') 
        AS x ( item )
```

Comment: just so i understand: method 1 is more or less "get the value of any element named PartnerName" while 2 is "get the value of any element named PartnerName contained within the specified namespaces"? Method 2 looks more precise - how would I include the PhysicalAddress subnode values in the second example?